# Unable to resolve "../Utilities/Platform" error with Metro bundler

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps, metro-bundler

I use React Native with Expo, Expo Router and Metro to build a map application. I used react-native-maps package. React-native-maps is not available for the web (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/), so I choose to use React Leaflet for the web. Then, in my app I do conditional rendering for rendering Leaflet on web and React Native Maps on Android and iOS.

My problem is that I have an error `Unable to resolve "../Utilities/Platform" from "node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactPrivate\ReactNativePrivateInterface.js"` error when I try to build for the web.

[image]

I found issues on Gihub with same problem : https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/4641. To resolve the problem, the person suggest to run a postinstall script. I am a big newbie and I'm not sure I did the things right.

What I did :

- Create a postinstall.js script at the root of my project
- Past the content of the postinstall script
- Run `node postinstall.js`

This did not solve my problem. I am pretty sure that was not the right way to do it.

What I expect to happen, is to not have the error, and being able to build for the web.

Comment: can you please share code of how you are rendering maps conditionally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you add this script into `package.json` post-install script like this

**Package.json**

```
 "scripts": {
   ....
    "postinstall": "node postinstall.js",
   ....
  }
```

**postinstall.js**

```
const chalk = require('chalk')
const { readFile, writeFile, copyFile } = require('fs').promises

console.log(chalk.green('here'))

function log(...args) {
  console.log(chalk.yellow('[react-native-maps]'), ...args)
}

reactNativeMaps = async function() {
  log(' Creating web compatibility of react-native-maps using an empty module loaded on web builds')
  const modulePath = 'node_modules/react-native-maps'
  await writeFile(`${modulePath}/lib/index.web.js`, 'module.exports = {}', 'utf-8')
  await copyFile(`${modulePath}/lib/index.d.ts`, `${modulePath}/lib/index.web.d.ts`)
  const pkg = JSON.parse(await readFile(`${modulePath}/package.json`))
  pkg['react-native'] = 'lib/index.js'
  pkg['main'] = 'lib/index.web.js'
  await writeFile(`${modulePath}/package.json`, JSON.stringify(pkg, null, 2), 'utf-8')
  log('✅ script ran successfully')
}

reactNativeMaps()
```

after this install node_modules by `npm i` or `yarn install`, installing node_module will run this patch

Don't forget to run `npx react-native start --reset-cache` command

**Note:** After running the patch successfully, just verify that if this file exists or not `node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/index.web.js`

Comment: Not OP, but even after I ran that I still had issues running. I have the same setup as OP. I tried wrapping the component to be rendered in `Platform.select`, but it seems that expo still tries to build both components and reactive native maps was still having issues.

Comment: @K.Shores I think, you are doing something wrong, can you connect with me on LinkedIn, we can debug it on call https://www.linkedin.com/in/numandev/